# Comparing two RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compare, rdd

I have two RDD[Array[String]], let's call them rdd1 and rdd2. 
I would create a new RDD containing just the entries of rdd2 not in rdd1 (based on a key).
I use Spark on Scala via Intellij.

I grouped rdd1 and rdd2 by a key (I will compare just the keys of the two rdds):

```
val rdd1Grouped = rdd1.groupBy(line => line(0))
val rdd2Grouped = rdd2.groupBy(line => line(0))
```

Then, I used a `leftOuterJoin`:

```
val output = rdd1Grouped.leftOuterJoin(rdd2Grouped).collect {
  case (k, (v, None)) => (k, v)
}
```

but this doesn't seem to give the correct result.

What's wrong with it? Any suggests?

*Example of RDDS (every line is an Array[String], ofc):*

```
rdd1                        rdd2                  output (in some form)

1,18/6/2016               2,9/6/2016                  2,9/6/2016
1,18/6/2016               2,9/6/2016 
1,18/6/2016               2,9/6/2016
1,18/6/2016               2,9/6/2016
1,18/6/2016               1,20/6/2016
3,18/6/2016               1,20/6/2016 
3,18/6/2016               1,20/6/2016
3,18/6/2016
3,18/6/2016
3,18/6/2016
```

In this case I wanna add just the entry "2,9/6/2016" because the key "2" is not in rdd1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> new RDD containing just the entries of rdd2 not in rdd1

left join would retain all keys in rdd1 and append columns of RDD2 matching key values. So clearly left join/outer join is not the solution.

`rdd1Grouped.subtractByKey(rdd2Grouped)` would be apt in your case.

P.S. : Also note that if rdd1 is smaller better broadcast it. In that way, only second rdd would be streamed at the time of subtract.

Comment: since `rdd1` and `rdd2` are not RDDs of tuples, subtractByKey can't really be called on them as-is. You're probably missing some calls to `keyBy`, e.g. `rdd1.keyBy(_(0)).subtractByKey(rdd2.keyBy(_(0))).values`

Comment: correct, I should use rdd1Grouped and rdd2Grouped, instead of just rdd1 and rdd2. Correcting now in my answer.

Comment: actually the grouping is redundant (and, often expensive), and it changes the result type - I think `keyBy` makes more sense here.

Comment: you are right, However, incase you want list of values for same key Grouping is best option.

Comment: it doesn't perform any reduction, and doesn't filter duplicates - `rdd.keyBy(f)` is equivalent to `rdd.map(v => (f(v), v))` - it transform each value to a tuple of (key, value) using the given function to create the key

Answer (score 1):

Switch `rdd1Grouped` and `rdd2Grouped`, and then use `filter`:

```
val output = rdd2Grouped.leftOuterJoin(rdd1Grouped).filter( line => {
  line._2._2.isEmpty
}).collect
```