# Spark RDD subtract doesn't work?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have two `RDD[MyModel]`: `R1` and `R2`. Here is the `MyModel` class:

```
case class MyModel(id: Int, name: String, hour: Long)
```

I want to remove elements from `R1` if elements exist in `R2`. This is what I tried:

```
val R3 = R1.subtract(R2).
```

However, `R1` is the same with `R3` (I am sure there are common elements between `R1` and `R2`)

Do I need to broadcast the smaller RDD to make subtract work? Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: What type of values does the `RDD` hold?

Comment: You can find some tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969286/comparing-two-rdds

Comment: Please post sample data, that RDD contains and Spark Version used.

Comment: The RDD contains an object class MyModel. Here is the MyModel class:     case class MyModel(id: Int, name: String, hour: Long)

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(MyModel(1, "AAA", 1000), MyModel(2, "ABC", 2000)))
scala> val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(MyModel(1, "AAA", 1000), MyModel(3, "WWW", 5000)))

scala> val rdd1_id1 = rdd1.filter(_.id == 1).first
rdd1_id1: MyModel = MyModel(1,AAA,1000)

scala> val rdd2_id1 = rdd2.filter(_.id == 1).first
rdd2_id1: MyModel = MyModel(1,AAA,1000)
```

The 2 seem to be identical and as per Scala's case class equals default implementation you would expect them to be equal but they are not.

```
rdd1_id1.equals(rdd2_id1)
res13: Boolean = false
```

More info on that in this post and possible solutions: http://jnordenberg.blogspot.ch/2009/04/equality-mutability-and-products.html

For a simple fix, I would, on the other hand, use Datasets, if possible:

```
scala> rdd1.toDS.except(rdd2.toDS).show
+---+----+----+
| id|name|hour|
+---+----+----+
|  2| ABC|2000|
+---+----+----+
```